# Flot Graph for speed vs time

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I am trying to display a speed/time graph using flot. I receive data from a servlet.
I have a large number of GPS tracking events with time-stamp,speed,locations etc.
If a user choose to view graph for say 2 days , the graph looks like this : 
[image]

this is because their is a long pause between gps events. (**horizontal is time in hours and vertical is speed in km/hr**)

Now if a user choose to view graph for a small time say 10 hrs or something like that(where their is no long pause in gps events) the graph looks perfect like this  :
[image]

The data which creates the graph is [here](http://rapidpaste.com/s/7e58e11c2d)

As you can see, the first graph is just unreadable, My question is how can I make the first graph more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like a mirrored logaritmic scale. Flot allows you to configure the steps of the chart.

Something like ([copied from here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md)):

```
xaxis: {
    transform: function (v) { return Math.log(v); },
    inverseTransform: function (v) { return Math.exp(v); }
}
```

Comment: `$.plot($("#placeholder"),
                     [{data:d,
                         points: { show: true, radius: 3},
                         lines:{show:true,fill:true},
                         xaxis: {
                             transform: function (v) { return Math.log(v); },
                             inverseTransform: function (v) { return Math.exp(v); }
                         }
                         }]
                      );
    }`

Comment: something like that, but you should play around with the transform function to change it to your needs